# Suggestions to go for AJAX or jQuery for auto-suggestion(completion)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I have examples for auto-suggestion(completion) with AJAX version, jQuery version. AJAX is more cross browsers compatible, jQuery is very neat but have some issues if using IE or older versions such as setting height of the list.

The problem is, website I'm creating is for one of those nations who are using old versions of everything so I should be very careful.

I myself used, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) AJAX model many times and learned jQuery autocomplete yesterday which works fine for me but won't for people I mentioned.

For this particular subject, I would like to know you thoughts about which auto-suggestion(completion) example would be same, or any example links.

Mush appreciated, thanks

Comment: jQuery has been designed to work (in a consistent way) on ALL browsers, so am surprised at that - that's one of the whole points of jQuery... and has always worked for me on all browsers!

Comment: `ui-autocomplete height` doesn't work properly in all browsers though. There are fixes but still doesn't look same in all.

Comment: GLOW has been designed to work in a MORE consistent way than jQuery. http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/

Comment: @MaxMax As long as the autocomplete is usable, I'm not sure I'd really care much about small height differences in that area...

Comment: what browsers/versions will your users be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is a concept (Asynchronous Javascript XML, or something like that). jQuery is a Javascript framework, which makes it easier to do cross-browser AJAX requests.

Unless you have a really good reason not to use jQuery¹, I'd use jQuery for this. jQuery UI supports autocomplete as well: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

¹ If you're already using a different library, Prototype, Ext, etc, these usually have similar support for making cross-browser ajax requests easier as well. Read the docs :)

Comment: I always want to use jQuery but as I said before "ui-autocomplete height doesn't work properly in all browsers". Returned list is very long so I had to limit the height not to go all the way down to the end of the screen.

Comment: You're not saying anything about how it doesn't work properly in your post.

Comment: :) Look what my first comment says above. "I always want to use jQuery but as I said before "ui-autocomplete height doesn't work properly in all browsers". Returned list is very long so I had to limit the height not to go all the way down to the end of the screen."

Comment: You still aren't telling me how it doesn't work properly. Does the height differ between browsers? Is the height limit ignored in some browsers? What's the problem?

Comment: If it's just a few browsers (especially if they are outdated) and it's just a cosmetic problem (the auto-complete is still usable), then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Don't worry about this post anymore because I am limiting data in response not to use height. Thanks for everything though.